# Execute Select Statement at Cassandra

Tags: caching, cassandra, memcached, cassandra-3.0

I have been a problem in Cassandra. Please help me..

I am executing Select statement at 500K rows table at intervals 1 millisecond. After some time I get message `"All host(s) tried for query failed. First host tried, 10.1.60.12:9042: Host considered as DOWN. See innerErrors"`.

I run select statement the fallowing:

```
select * from demo.users
```

this returning to me 5K rows. There are 500K rows in the users table.

I don't know what is wrong. I have not changed the `cassandra.yaml` file.

I need to make settings for the memory cache? There is too much disk i/o when I run select statement.

Please help me

Comment: Cassandra just doesn't do well with unbound queries.  It's not a reporting tool.

Comment: for `select *` your query must hit every node in the cluster, basically defeating the whole idea of distributed data and replication. Use spark or some other tool if you need this kind of query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A range query (select * with no primary key or token ranges) can be a very expensive query that has to hit at least 1 of every replica set (depend on size of dataset). If your trying to read the entire dataset or doing batch processing either be best to use spark connector or behave like it, and query individual token ranges to prevent putting too much load on coordinators.

If you are going to be using inefficient queries (which is fine, just don't expect the same throughput as normal reads) you will probably need more resources or some specialized tuning. You could add more nodes or look into whats causing it to go DOWN. Most likely its GCs from heap load, so can check GC log. If you have the memory available you can increase heap. Would be good idea to max heap size since with reading everything, system caches are not going to be as meaningful. Use G1 once over 16gb (which you should be) in the jvm.options.